# How to prevent Firefox to add particular sites to history?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

When I look into my Firefox history trying to find a page I've visited recently, the history is usually overwhelmed with google.com search, GMail, Google+ and Google Reader pages (and some other pages equally useless to account).

Is there a way (an extension perhaps) to fight this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is.

[HistoryBlock 1.4.0.5](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/historyblock/)

> About this Add-on
>   This tool will allow the user to specify a list of hosts to be blocked from the history tab, the recently closed tabs list, and the download manager (ctrl+j). HistoryBlock is a Firefox Add-on that works comparably to the newly created Chrome's Incognito mode, but without the necessity of switching modes while using the browser (or opening in new windows, etc).
>
> Click the "Options" button under the addon and add a hostname to be blocked.
>
> ### Examples
>
> ebay.com, worldofwarcraft.com, games.yahoo.com
>
> Alternatively, now you can simply right-click on a page and hit "Block This!" to automatically add the hostname and/or subdomain of the current page to the blacklist.

[Form History Control 1.3.0.6](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/form-history-control/)

> About this Add-on
>
> An extension to View and Manage all form data that has been saved by the web browser giving you full control over what is stored, what is cleaned up or not, and when to perform a cleanup. This extension even allows you to control selectively for which webpages form history data is stored (either blacklist or whitelist). Also stores text from editor fields as you type for easy recovery in case of disaster.

Comment: I have tried HistoryBlock. It does not work :-(

Comment: @ivan did you restart firefox ? I tried it and it works for me

Comment: I did. About hundred times since then.